# Unique ID don't fix "unique key" error when rendering nested lists in React

Tags: reactjs

I can't get rid of the classic React *"Each child in the list should have a unique key"*.
I'm rendering a big array, with items that can have sub items.

To prevent all of this, i created a data structure with unique id for every item.

This is my data:

```
export const assetListConfig: RolesListItem[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: t('Asset creation'),
    name: 'Asset-Create',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: t('Edit asset info'),
    name: 'Asset-Edit',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: t('Archive'),
    name: 'Asset-Archive',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: t('Delete'),
    name: 'Asset-Delete',
    type: 'switch',
    subLists: [
      {
        subListWatch: 'Asset-Delete',
        items: [
          {
            id: 5,
            title: t('Bulk deletion'),
            name: 'Asset-Delete-Bulk',
            type: 'switch',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: t('Resources'),
    name: 'Asset-Manage-Resources',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: t('Enable public'),
    name: 'Asset-Set-Public',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: t('Enable redirect'),
    name: 'Asset-Set-Redirect',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: t('Enable tickets'),
    name: 'Asset-Enable-Tickets',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    title: t('Edit hierarchy'),
    name: 'Asset-Edit-Hierarchy',
    type: 'switch',
    itemWatch: ['Asset-Edit'],
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    title: t('Locations'),
    name: 'Asset-Location',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    title: t('Manage asset tags'),
    name: 'Asset-Manage-Tags',
    type: 'switch',
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    title: t('Logbook'),
    name: 'Asset-Logbook-Read',
    type: 'switch',
    subLists: [
      {
        subListWatch: 'Asset-Logbook-Read',
        items: [
          {
            id: 14,
            title: t('Comment'),
            name: 'Asset-Logbook-Comment',
            type: 'switch',
          },
          {
            id: 15,
            title: t('Allow export'),
            name: 'Asset-Logbook-Export',
            type: 'switch',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    title: t('Components'),
    name: 'Component-Read',
    type: 'switch',
    subLists: [
      {
        subListWatch: 'Component-Read',
        items: [
          {
            id: 17,
            title: t('Instances'),
            name: 'Component-Instance',
            type: 'radio',
            radioOptions: [
              { label: t('Manage'), value: 'Component-Instance-Manage' },
              {
                label: t('Delete'),
                value: 'Component-Instance-Delete',
                inputWatch: 'Component-Instance-Manage',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 18,
            title: t('Models'),
            name: 'Component-Model',
            type: 'radio',
            radioOptions: [
              {
                label: t('Manage'),
                value: 'Component-Model-Manage',
                inputWatch: 'Component-Instance-Manage',
              },
              {
                label: t('Delete'),
                value: 'Component-Model-Delete',
                inputWatch: 'Component-Model-Manage',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    title: t('Workshifts'),
    name: 'Asset-Running-Read',
    type: 'switch',
    subLists: [
      {
        subListWatch: 'Asset-Running-Read',
        items: [
          {
            id: 20,
            title: t('Manage status'),
            name: 'Asset-Running-Status-Manage',
            type: 'switch',
          },
          {
            id: 21,
            title: t('Manage expectations'),
            name: 'Asset-Running-Expectation-Manage',
            type: 'switch',
          },
          {
            id: 22,
            title: t('Manage schedules'),
            name: 'Asset-Running-Schedule-Manage',
            type: 'switch',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I render lists with .map also for radiogroup options and item sublists.

This is the component in which I get the error:

```
import shortid from 'shortid'

export const UserRolesList: React.FC<ListItemProps> = ({
  listConfig,
  userData,
  isSubList = false,
}) => {
  
  handleChange  ecc ecc...


  return (
    <RolesListWrapper isSubList={isSubList}>
      <ul
        className="list--unbulleted display--ib full-width"
      >
       
       /* FIRST LIST RENDERING */

        **{listConfig.map((listItem, index) => {
          const {
            name,
            title,
            type,
            radioOptions = [],
            selectOptions = [],
            id: skillId,
            subLists,
          } = listItem;**

          const visibleOptions = renderVisibleOptions(radioOptions);

          return (
            <>
              {isListItemVisible(listItem) ? (
                **<li
                  className={`pad pad-double--sides shadow--list-item ${
                    index !== listConfig.length - 1 ? 'push--bottom' : ''
                  }`}
                  key={skillId}
                  style={
                    isSubList
                      ? {
                          padding: '0',
                          boxShadow: 'none',
                        }
                      : {
                          width: 'auto',
                          minWidth: '350px',
                        }
                  }
                >**
                  <div className="full-width flex--space-items">
                    <div
                      className="pad flex--align-center"
                      style={{
                        paddingLeft: isSubList ? 'var(--base-space)' : '',
                        flexBasis: '160px',
                      }}
                    >
                      {title}
                    </div>
                    {type === 'switch' ? (
                      <div className="pad flex--align-center">
                        <Switch
                          onColor="#21b151"
                          offColor="#e02f2f"
                          checked={findActiveSkill(name)}
                          onChange={() => handleSkillChange(name)}
                          disabled={isAddingSkill || isRemovingSkill}
                        />
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                    {type === 'radio' ? (
                      **<div
                        className="flex-item--fill"
                        style={{
                          display: 'grid',
                          gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3,1fr)',
                        }}
                      >

                        /* SECOND LIST RENDERING */

                        {visibleOptions.map((opt) => (
                          <div
                            className="flex--align-center"
                            style={{
                              gridColumn: opt.value.includes('Delete')
                                ? '3'
                                : undefined,
                            }}
                            key={shortid.generate()}
                          >**
                            <input
                              type="checkbox"
                              className="qtrack-form-input__selection"
                              value={opt.value}
                              id={opt.value}
                              checked={findActiveSkill(opt.value)}
                              onChange={(e) =>
                                handleSkillChange(e.target.value)
                              }
                              disabled={isAddingSkill || isRemovingSkill}
                            />
                            <label
                              style={{ margin: '5px 0' }}
                              htmlFor={opt.value}
                            >
                              {opt.label}
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                    {type === 'select' ? (
                      <div style={{ margin: '0', minWidth: '220px' }}>
                        <SimpleSelect
                          selectOptions={selectOptions}
                          value={selectOptions.find((opt) =>
                            skills.includes(opt.value),
                          )}
                          isMulti={false}
                          isClearable
                          errors={undefined}
                          onChange={(e: string) => handleSelectChange(e, name)}
                          name="roles-select"
                          isDisabled={isAddingSkill || isRemovingSkill}
                        />
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                  {subLists ? (
                    <SubListHandler subLists={subLists} userData={userData} />
                  ) : null}
                </li>
              ) : null}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </RolesListWrapper>
  );
};
```

And this is the component in which I render the sublists:

```
export const SubListHandler: React.FC<{
  subLists: RolesList[];
  userData: UserData;
}> = ({ subLists, userData }) => (
  <>

    /* THIRD AND LAST LIST RENDER */

    {subLists.map((list) => {
      const { subListWatch, items: subItems } = list;
      const isSubListVisible = userData.skills.includes(subListWatch);
      **const subListId = shortid.generate();**

      return (
        <div key={subListId}>
          {isSubListVisible ? (
            **<div>**
              {list.title ? (
                <div className="txt--bold pad--left push--top">
                  {list.title}
                </div>
              ) : null}
              <div className="push--ends pad--left">
                <UserRolesList
                  listConfig={subItems}
                  userData={userData}
                  isSubList
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

As you can see, I'm using unique IDs for all the three map methods in my component.
This is confirmed when I log the IDs I used in the console. They're all different.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm messing something with the conditional rendering or nested components

I tried to highlight when the list rendering happens in the code.
This seems pretty straighforward to me as I have unique ids for every list child, but it always throws me an error.

Let me know if you find something wrong with my code.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue with table rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the unique id in the 'key' prop of the list items. ie. -

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={todo.id}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter if I use <div> or <li> as long I put a key prop, as I did in the code for all the list children. Anyway, I changed everything to a <li> as you suggested but it still throws the error.

Comment: Where is the error throwing? can you show the error message? That was my mistake, I missed the key prop in there, thought it was missing.

Comment: The usual one: "Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of".